# "Preferred Graphics Processor" setting in NVIDIA control panel is missing, how to restore?

Tags: rise-of-industry

Some games allow selecting a specific graphics output, for those that don't, I'd like to specify a different default than is currently used. This should be possible with the NVIDIA Control Panel:

[image: NVIDIA Control Panel]

It [should have an option](https://appuals.com/how-to-change-default-display-adapter-on-windows-7-8-10/) to select the preferred graphics processor.

Changing this setting has worked as expected in Path of Exile, however in the Control Panel I don't have this option at all. My one graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080. My 2 monitors are connected through a DVI connector (the current default) and a DisplayPort connector, both directly on the graphics card.

Does anyone know why this option isn't available?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your GPU's drivers?